# Adding bullet points to a text area

Tags: textarea, points

Is there a way to add bullet points to an HTML textarea?

I want to add a simple feature where a bullet point is added for every line in a text area (similar to a list bullet points).

Comment: This answer seems helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042927/5746368

Answer (score 16):

You can't do that, but there is another way. Delete the textarea:

```html
<section id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
    <ul>
        <li>List item here</li>
        <li>List item here</li>
        <li>List item here</li>
        <li>List item here</li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Note that contenteditable allows the user to do things like paste rich html text into a list item. For many this might be an unwanted side effect.

Comment: `contenteditable` is an amazing feature! You can apply it to any dom element

Answer (score 2):

I think you will not able to add bullet points (i.e., rich text) in a *textarea (HTML form)* or any other HTML input control.

But you may achieve the result by adding a [rich-text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor).

*Or* you need to write jQuery code to handle the event and display the result, like if the user is simply viewing content, then show that in HTML and CSS format and if the user clicks on the content then show text area and allow to add more text.

```html
<textarea id="banner-message" class="message" style="display:none">
</textarea>

<div id="display" class="message" style="overflow-y:auto">
</div>
```

```javascript
var strings = [];
strings.push(
  "first text",
  "second text",
  "third text"
);

var htmlContent = '';
var textAreaContent = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    strings.forEach(element => htmlContent += "<li>" + element + "</li>");
    $("#display").html(htmlContent);
    var i = 1;

    strings.forEach(function(element) {
        if(strings.length == i)
            textAreaContent += ">" + element;
        else
            textAreaContent += ">" + element + "\n";
        i++;
    });
    $("#banner-message").val(textAreaContent);
})

$("#display").click(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $("#banner-message").css("display", "");
    var currentText = $("#banner-message").val();
    //currentText += "\n>";
    $("#banner-message").val(currentText);
    $("#banner-message").focus();
});

$("#banner-message").blur(function() {
    var currentText = $("#banner-message").val();
    var plainText = currentText.replace(/>/g, "")
    var splitText = plainText.split("\n");
    console.log(splitText);
    htmlContent = '';
    splitText.forEach(element => htmlContent += "<li>" + element + "</li>");
    $("#display").html(htmlContent);

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $("#display").css("display", "");
})

$("#banner-message").keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        text += ">";
        $(this).val(text);
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v5unL369/1/

Comment: I forked the jsFiddle above to add functionality for users to input items to the list; see https://jsfiddle.net/v9sq62eo/1/.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job very nicely. Set BULLET to whatever character code you prefer.

```html
<head>
    <script>
        var CRLF   = 10;
        var BULLET = String.fromCharCode(45);

        function Init() {
            if (txt.addEventListener) txt.addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
        }

        function OnInput(event) {
            char = event.target.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
            nowLen = txt.value.length;

            if (nowLen > prevLen.value) {
                if (char == CRLF) txt.value = txt.value + BULLET + " ";
                if (nowLen == 1) txt.value = BULLET + " " + txt.value;
            }
            prevLen.value = nowLen;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="Init ();">
    <h4>Automatic bullets in a text box</h4>
    <textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="prevLen" value="0"/>
</body>
```

Comment: This works great, just remove the redundant oninput="" attribute from the textarea html, otherwise you'll be calling it twice.

Comment: Thanks @harvest316, I've removed the redundant oninput="" from the code.

Comment: This works good, however, it doesn't add a new bullet when you are in the middle of the text contents and press enter. Just when you are at the end of the current text value. Any idea how you could get that working?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by the select change function through catching the id and reduce the code:

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $("#Projectone").focus(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('Projectone').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('Projectone').value += '• ';
            }
        });

        $("#Projectone").keyup(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                document.getElementById('Projectone').value += '• ';
            }
            var txtval = document.getElementById('Projectone').value;
            if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
                document.getElementById('Projectone').value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
            }
        });

        // Second project
        $("#Projecttwo").focus(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('Projecttwo').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('Projecttwo').value += '• ';
            }
        });

        $("#Projecttwo").keyup(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                document.getElementById('Projecttwo').value += '• ';
            }
            var txtval = document.getElementById('Projecttwo').value;
            if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
                document.getElementById('Projecttwo').value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
            }
        });


        // Third project
        $("#Projectthree").focus(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('Projectthree').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('Projectthree').value += '• ';
            }
        });

        $("#Projectthree").keyup(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                document.getElementById('Projectthree').value += '• ';
            }
            var txtval = document.getElementById('Projectthree').value;
            if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
                document.getElementById('Projectthree').value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
            }
        });

        // Fourth project
        $("#Projectfour").focus(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('Projectfour').value === '') {
                document.getElementById('Projectfour').value += '• ';
            }
        });

        $("#Projectfour").keyup(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                document.getElementById('Projectfour').value += '• ';
            }
            var txtval = document.getElementById('Projectfour').value;
            if (txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n') {
                document.getElementById('Projectfour').value = txtval.substring(0, txtval.length - 1);
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? There ***are*** some bullet point characters in there ("•"). An explanation would be in order. E.g., what do you mean by "catching the id" and "reduce the code". What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57433349/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who come accross this problem, here is how I did it:

```css
.text-area {
  display: list-item;
  margin-left : 1em;
  outline: none;
}
.text-area div {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-area" contenteditable="true">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't.

But, you can get a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor where you can use bullets lists, and more (like images, bold, italic, etc.).

Those WYSIWYG editors are fully customizable, so you can enable just the options you need.

The most famous ones are:

- [CKEditor](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20CKEDITOR)
- [TinyMCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the hexadecimal Unicode value: `\u2022` ([BULLET](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8220&number=128)).  So you might add bullets to new lines in this manner:

`$textarea.val($textarea.val().replace(/\n/g,"\n\u2022").replace(/\r/g,"\r\u2022"))`

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the below characters &#9679 for the bullets:

```html
<textarea rows="6" cols="20">
    &#9679 Item1
    &#9679 Item2
    &#9679 Item3
    &#9679 Item4
    &#9679 Item5
</textarea>
```

Comment: What is 9679? Unicode code point [U+25CF](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9669&number=128) (BLACK CIRCLE)?