# Dynamically adding a text bullet to a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a form that is pretty dynamically created based off of a project created in Pageflex Studio. I can add script or HTML elements above the text area and I can add script or HTML elements below the text area but I cannot directly edit the text area HTML.

Essentially, I have a textarea that was dynamically added that I can only target using a JQuery selector. I need to add some sort of functionality to this (either a button the user can press or just by pressing enter) where the user can create a text bullet (so not a bullet created with HTML ul/li).

So I want the final result to look something like this:

[image]

I tried using the code found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732789/adding-bullet-points-to-a-text-area) but had trouble getting it to access the textarea. I'm a bit rusty on my JavaScript so I feel like I'm missing something simple here but just not getting it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "access to the text area". Why does $('textarea') not work?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet with the attempt you speak about in the last paragraph, so we see for ourselves what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

you can change bullet size copy any one [⬤,●,•] and set on the code

```js
$("#btn_add").click(function(){
document.getElementById('todolist').value +='● ' + $("#entryText").val()+"\n";
});
```

```css
#todolist {width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="enter todo value" id="entryText" />
<button id="btn_add">add</button>

    <textarea id="todolist" class="todolist" name="todolist" rows="10" placeholder="Maintain your pending tasks"></textarea>
```

[image]